# Multiple checkboxes show multiple colors VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The code below shows three check boxes in vba, each of them (if checked) highlight a specific cell background in my workbook yellow. Is it possible so If one checkbox is checked the background will be yellow, if two are selected it will be orange and if three are selected it will be red. Also if none are selected there will be no fill for the background. I have the no fill and yellow part so far but I cant figure out how to add the other two colors. Anything helps, thanks.

```
Sub CheckBox25_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 25")
        If .Value = xlOn Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C18").Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        Else: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C18").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub CheckBox26_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 26")
        If .Value = xlOn Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C18").Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        Else: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C18").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub CheckBox27_Click()
    With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 27")
        If .Value = xlOn Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C18").Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        Else: Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C18").Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in the same module as the above code:

```
Sub colorCell()
Dim CB25 As Long
Dim CB26 As Long
Dim CB27 As Long

CB25 = (ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 25").Value = xlOn) * -1
CB26 = (ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 26").Value = xlOn) * -1
CB27 = (ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 27").Value = xlOn) * -1

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C18").Interior
    Select Case CB25 + CB26 + CB27
        Case 1
            .ColorIndex = 27
        Case 2
            .ColorIndex = 27 'Change to your color
        Case 3
            .ColorIndex = 27 'Change to your color
        Case Else
            .ColorIndex = 0
    End Select
End With

End Sub
```

Then in each event change to be like this one:

```
Sub CheckBox25_Click()
    colorCell
End Sub
```

Now, every time one changes it will do the count and change the color accordingly.